# Advanced Installer How to get a variable instancename into EXE bootstrapper for pre-req install of SQL Express 2012

Tags: windows-installer, installation, sql-server-express, advanced-installer

How can i get the user to enter the instancename and password for installing SQL Express via Advanced Installers ( version 10.7.1 ) Exe bootstrapper (pre-install) ?

It there any trick to passing variables at that stage of the install?

I understand i can't use the feature-bases or post-install pre-req sections due to this this :
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting installer public properties from the command line using an Advanced Installer EXE is described here:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/exe-setup-file.html

However, you cannot add formatted references for public properties in the "Install Command Lines" section from the "Setup Files" tab of your SQL Server Express **pre-install** prerequisite. This is because the "Install Command Lines" fields only support formatted references when the prerequisite is **feature-based**.

This means you cannot set custom parameters from the command line when installing SQL Express setup, if you add the setup as a *pre-install* prerequisite.

Maybe Microsoft fixed the limitation of not being able to install SQL Express as a *feature* or *post-install* prerequisite. If not the only solution would be to use the approach from the tutorial you linked.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Mike. I have decided to create a c# windows forms app that will just accept the password then kick off the sql install.